# AS3 - Changing depth of an object from within said object

Tags: actionscript-3

So I have a bunch of objects (thumbnails) and I want every photo to be displayed on top of other photos once it's clicked. So what should I put inside the click handler inside the photo object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the magic

```
{container}.setChildIndex({clickedPhoto},{container}.numChildren);
```

where container holds all photos, clickedPhoto is the one that you clicked.

Edited: 
actualy i'm wrong this would do it on the Container. Inside the photo you have to do this

```
parent.setChildIndex(this, parent.numChildren);
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, actually what worked was   parent.setChildIndex(this,parent.numChildren-1);

Comment: Oh yea :), but happy to help :)